# Qyerying a one-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

So I have tables `Uploads` and `Avtors` (Authors). I am trying to write a query that will get me all the uploads for a given user + the author.

To achieve this I have the following function in my controller :

```
public function uploads()
        $uploads = Auth::user()->upload()->with('author')->paginate(10);

        return view('uploads')->with('uploads',$uploads);
    }
```

This function manages to get me all the uploads for a given user, but not the author :

When I debug with `dd` I get this :

[image]

My relationships in the models are difined in the following ways :

User:

```
 public function upload(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Upload');
    }
```

Avtor:

```
class Avtor extends Model
{
    public function uploads(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Upload');
    }
}
```

Upload:

```
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function author(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Avtor');
    }
```

Can anybody help me find out what am I doing wrong here because I can't by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`load()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) method with nested relationship dot syntax:

```
auht()->user()->load(['uploads', 'uploads.author'])->get();
```

In this case, you'll not need to pass any data to a view, just do this:

```
@foreach (auth()->user()->uploads as $upload)
```

Or you can use [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method:

```
$uploads = Upload::with('author')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->get();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I tried both, but unfortunately, they didn't work. The first gives me the following error : Call to undefined relationship [uploads] on model [App\User]. The second one isn't giving any errors, but author is null same as on the screenshot from my question.

Comment: @incense_stick just use real names of relationships and make sure the relationships are working (correct methods, foreign keys used etc).

Comment: Okay, I made the first one work but it's returning just a users array?

Comment: @incense_stick no, the first one loads relationships and attaches the data to `auth()->user()` object.

Comment: So where am I suppose to see this data when I debug with dd? Because all I can see is the data for the user.

Comment: Yep, just do `dd(auth()->user())` and you'll see all the data if the relationships were loaded correctly.

Comment: Okay, i saw the data, but author is still null :(

Comment: I guess the problem is in a custom FK. Try to define correct one with `return $this->belongsTo('App\Avtor', 'avtor_id');`

Comment: What can be wrong with my FK. It shows as a FK in the database. I defined it like this  Schema::table('uploads', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('avtor_id')->references('id')->on('avtors');
        });

Comment: You're ignoring [Laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions), so you need to define the relationship with FK as I've shown in the previous comment.

Comment: Yesm this worked! Had no idea about this. Thank you very much!